# Replace a certain string between two markers in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, gsub

i want to replace "\n" into "br" tag between code markers (in my case ```) before insering into the DB (im dealing with a textarea) , example :

````
```
echo "Hello";
echo "World!";
```

first line.
second line.
````

would become :

````
```<br/>echo "Hello";<br/>echo "World!";<br/>```
first line .
second line .
````

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want all of the line breaks (\n) inside code blocks to become br tags .

Comment: @Lofaif did three backticks are always paired?

Comment: @Lofaif if you want to replace all the `\n` within ``` to <br/> then why there isn't a br after first three backtick and why you placed `<br/>` for the newline which exists before second  ``` bacticks? seems like an odd for me.

Comment: that was just a mistake sorry , im just trying to deal with the code in a markdown editor .. while the syntax outside the code markers use p tags to seperate text , im having this problem when writing code !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
str = %q{
```
echo "Hello";
echo "World!";
```

first line.
second line.
}

pattern = %r{
  `{3}
  .*? 
  `{3}
}xm

str.gsub!(pattern) do |match|
  match.gsub!("\n", '<br/>')
end

puts str

--output:--

```<br/>echo "Hello";<br/>echo "World!";<br/>```

first line.
second line.
````